# 'Wave_read' object has no attribute 'read' in Python

Tags: python

I have this code and I want to open a .wav file when I run it but it shows error: 'Wave_read' object has no attribute 'read'

```
from wave import*

music = open(r'file.wav', 'rb')
music.read()
```

Comment: It seems there is an `open` method in `wave` package, do you really want to do that ? Also it's better to have explicit imports, to ensure you don't do thing you wouldn't want

Comment: What can I do to play the file's content?

Comment: You don't play music with python, use an audio player, like VLC

Comment: Oh okay thank you